# Cisco ASA VPN: Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa

During VPN reconfiguration we have met quite big issue with VPN traffic not passing to peer. Using packet-tracer we have have got following debug:

Phase 1 to Phase 9 passed successfully.
[...]

Phase: 10
Type: VPN
Subtype: encrypt
Result: DROP
Config:
Additional Information:

Result:
input-interface: internal
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: newiface
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: **drop**
Drop-reason: **(acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule**

We have googled lot of docs, but nothing helped.

Comment: What's the relevant crypto ACL look like, and what traffic are you simulating?

Answer (score 4):

Fortunatelly I'm already able to answer - I want to allow someone else to spare several hours and lot of headache.

we have had configured everything correctly - NAT, ACL, CACL, routes etc. But we we have forgot for one crucial thing - this interface was new and IPSEC was not enabled on that interface.

**crypto ikev1 enable newiface**

was the solution for our problem, after adding this command, everything (well, mostly) went up without problem. I haven't found mentioned this as possible solution for **(acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule**, so I decided to share it with others.

Comment: Ohh, that's an awful error message for the trace.  Good find, thanks a lot for sharing!

Comment: I'd like to link to my issue, which I think is likely more common: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57095/cannot-get-port-forward-working-on-asa-5505-drop-reason-acl-drop-flow-is-de/57222?noredirect=1#comment99633_57222